# No puedo acceder a mi API desplegada en Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, deployment, adonisjs

Realice los pasos para hacer un despliegue de mi aplicación API REST hecha en adonisjs, en el servicio de
heroku.

El proceso de despliegue no me genera ningún inconveniente, esto esta OK.

Sin embargo cuando hago alguna petición http (POST/GET/PATCH), lo unico que me regresa es un 502 "Heroku | Welcome to your new app".

**ejemplo:**
https://vast-lowlands-44144.herokuapp.com/api/usuarios/registro

**responde:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Heroku | Welcome to your new app!</title>
    <style type='text/css'>
</head>
  </html>
```

Ya inserte las variables de entorno, e incluso ya me hizo las migraciones a la BD que esta en AWS,pero no logro resolver el problema de acceder a las funcionalidades de mi app desplegada,¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: subiste simplemente un backen o hay un frontend también?

Comment: Solo es el back-end

Comment: la consola de heroku te muestra alguna advertencia?

Comment: en la parte de Activity Feed, tengo el siguiente error: Deployment failed c563ac9b

Comment: el repositorio es el siguiente:https://github.com/anzaEchoes/api_tienda